# writing datatrigger for local: (.xaml file)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is it possible to write trigger for local:FruitTemplate and local:AnimalTemplate.
I have a situation where Fruit is clicked FruitTemplate should be visible and when Animal is clicked AnimalTemplate should be visible. I would like some samples on how i can achieve it. Thanks in advance.

```
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <local:FruitTemplate/>
                        <local:AnimalTemplate/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to triggers, you can consider the built-in `DateTemplateSelectors` that can be used for modifying the `DataTemplate` presentation based on the bound item's type. In this way you can store the alternate templates as separate resources and pick the one you need in the `SelectTemplate` method. Personally, I feel this approach to be more natural than a UI trigger and it is still MVVM compliant.
[`ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=net-5.0) is the entry point that can use. Check the article, there are some code samples.